# Question about a language in the alphabet {(,)}

Tags: formal-languages

Let our alphabet be $\{x,(,),+\}$. A term is inductively defined as follows. $x$ is a term. If $s$ and $t$ are terms, so is $(s+t)$. Let $L$ denote the language of terms, and let $L'$ denote the same language after we delete all $x$'s and $+$'s from all the terms. This is in fact a language in the reduced alphabet $\{(,)\}$. The language $PAREN$ of balanced parentheses in this same alphabet is inductively defined by the rules: 1. The empty string is a member. 2. If $a$ and $b$ are members, so is $ab$. 3. If $a$ is a member, so is $(a)$. Let $(PAREN)$ refer to the language where every member is enclosed with one outermost parentheses. My conjecture is that the union of the language containing the empty string, along with $(PAREN)$ is equal to $L'$. Is this true? And if not, is it a subset of $L'$.

Comment: @Adayah If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L'$ is a strict subset of $(PAREN) \cup \{ \text{empty word} \}$, because the parentheses in $L'$ only correspond to trees with at most two children while those in $(PAREN)$ correspond to any tree. For example, $(()()()()())$ is in $(PAREN)$ but not in $L'$.

Comment: How do I know there isn't a complicated term whose parentheses look like (()()()()())?

Comment: From definition of $L'$, every term is either $\varepsilon$ or $(ab)$ where $a, b \in L'$. Now again $a, b$ are each either empty or of form $(cd)$, where $c, d \in L'$, so the possibilites are: $\varepsilon, \ (), \ ((cd)), \ ((c_1d_1)(c_2d_2))$. But $c, d$ or $c_1, d_1, c_2, d_2$ are balanced parenthesis as well, so they cannot be anything like $)()($ which they would need to be in order to produce $(()()()()())$ in the end.

Comment: @user107952: $L'$ has the grammar $S\to \varepsilon \mid (SS)$. If you eliminate $\varepsilon$-productions, you get $S\to\varepsilon\mid T,\;\; T\to ()\mid (T)\mid (TT)$, which is LL, so you can attempt to parse `(()()()())` and see it fail.